# is it safe to return object from namespace?

Tags: c++, object, c++11, namespaces

Is it safe to return object from within namespace. In below code `call()` is returning bag object by value. But scope of newly created object is within namespace... so had a doubt if it is right way to do it.

```
namespace abc{

class bag{

    public:
        bag()
        {
            cout<<"\nconstructor called";
        }
        ~bag()
        {
            cout<<"\ndestructor called";
        }
        bag(bag &c)
        {
            cout<<"\ncopy constructor called";
        }
        bag call()
        {
            bag f;
            return f;
        }
};
```

My second question is regarding copy constructor. 
In `main()` i am trying to call copy constructor by using following expression, but compiler is throwing error... how can i achieve this

```
abc::bag b;
abc::bag c=b.call(); // trying to call copy constructor ,but getting compile time error
```

Comment: What is the compile-time error?

Comment: You do not have doubts, you have questions, see http://www.cs.uic.edu/bin/view/Jakob/IndianEnglish

Answer (score 4):

There is no danger whatsover in returning an object from a member function of a class that belongs to some namespace. I fail to see what problems you may be referring to.

As for the second problem, that is because the expression:

```
b.call()
```

Yields an rvalue (a temporary object), and your copy constructor accepts an lvalue reference:

```
bag(bag& c)
```

Since lvalue references cannot bind to rvalues, the compiler is shouting at you. You should let your copy constructor have the canonical signature and accept an lvalue reference to `const` instead (lvalue references to `const` can bind to rvalues):

```
bag(bag const& c)
//      ^^^^^
```

After all, you normally do not need/want to modify the object you want to create a copy of.

Comment: @user1057741: I'm really not sure I understand what you are saying :(

Answer (score 2):

namespace is *only* a thing used to resolve names. It has no effect on object lifetime or anything else. So if your code was right outside namespace it is good inside.

And you should properly use `const` in copy ctor (and missing op=) signature.

Answer (score 0):

`abc::bag c=b.call();` This has nothing to do with a copy constructor. To call the copy constructor you have implemented you should write `abc::bag c( &b )`

Comment: `&b` yields a pointer to an `abc::bag` (`abc::bag *`). A copy-constructor usually takes a const-reference (`abc::bag const &`). So your code won't call the copy-constructor either.